# Is SPA solution proper for developing an big data approach applications?

Tags: single-page-application, multi-page-application

Let say, We have a system which contains a complex user interface, and I have to show the data in many kinds of format such as `data-tables`, `diagrams`, `lists`, `detail-view`, etc. And we have to load huge amount of data and render it into a page. I need to know, is `SPA` application proper for this kind of application or I should move to `multi-page` web-application architecture?

Comment: Hi Siavash, please take a look at [ask]. I've flagged this question to be closed as per the **Off topic** guidelines. This question is both too broad and opinionated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the most part any framework is suitable for large amounts of data, as long as it is loaded in a reasonable manner and you do not expect to load hundreds of MB of data into display at once but load it dynamically when it is required. Angular itself is great for dealing with substantial data on the front end as it is all referenced in one common location.

For very large amounts of data which have to be loaded in at once a SPA app is less viable than a native application or a multipage website.

One large consideration to make is that Angular is not compatible with older browsers across devices.